# Group data by a column in Prometheus/Grafana for last 24h

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am new to Grafana/Prometheus.

I am trying to extract data for API usage based on API key per day. so for example I am looking to create a table with following

| API Key | Calls |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 5000 |
| 12356 | 4000 |

How do I group api key usage by by api key?

Here is my data

api_key_counter_200_total{X_API_KEY="123", instance="a", job="prometheus"}

Comment: You provided a query but no data, so I need to guess. Maybe just remove the filter for X_API_KEY from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Adding following transform gave me expected results.

[image]